# VBA insert 2 rows below cell containing value

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to insert 2 blank rows below every cell containing the value "yes" in my sheet.
My code seems to run infinitely when executed and when I disrupt the macro, I see that way more than 2 rows had been added.

```
For Each rng In .UsedRange
    If InStr(rng.Value, "yes") Then
        rng.EntireRow.Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you increase `.UsedRange` with each insert.

In this case it is better to check the range from bottom up:

```vb
Public Sub insertRowIfYes(rgColumnWithYes As Range)

Dim i As Long
For i = rgColumnWithYes.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rgColumnWithYes.Rows(i).Value = "yes" Then
        rgColumnWithYes.Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

You have to call this sub with the range of the yes-column.